# Aquiring caffeine after the apocalypse?

Tags: apocalypse, food

The world is mostly safe now, but everything has been scavenged from the old world. I live where winter always reached [-20F or lower outside](https://www.gardenia.net/plants/hardiness-zones/4). Our colony has a hundred people and a few working electronic devices, no one else is better off.

The last of my scavenged coffee is running out. I am open to anything but caffeine is needed in my morning ritual.

How can I get enough caffeine to replace my 16oz of coffee a day without being able to purchase/scavange it?

Comment: What's more important than latitude is climate. I know in the United States that the department of agriculture has growing regions that they use to classify what can grow where.

Comment: It's not all too clear what you're asking. Are you wondering how you should most effectively scavage the buildings in your environs for coffee? Or is this a question about how you can cultivate/process coffee plants in your specific world? To answer either of these properly you'll need to give us more details about the state of your vicinities after this collapse. For instance: What resources do you have? Electricity? Is it safe to go outside?

Comment: @AngelPray it is more cultivation and processing. At this point it is safe to go outside, and electricity is extremely limited but available. I will add more details to the question.

Comment: @sphennings I am aiming for growing regions of 4 and lower, or  temperatures of -20F or lower in the winter

Comment: Are greenhouses acceptable? Or are you interested in plants you can leave outside?

Comment: @sphennings it is acceptable, but it is hard to get existing seeds/sprouts from more than 3 growing zones away, or regions with the lowest temperatures of 0F in the winter

Comment: Then your greenhouse will be a great effort, well-insulated, climate-controlled. Post-apocalyptic children will work themselves to collapse keeping it running, instead of learning the skills they need to survive and to build the new world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a greenhouse or a growing room and grow the following:

- Plants: Guaraná, Yerba Maté, Cola nut (Kola nut), Cacao, and all the coffee/tea plants.

It's your only option.

Comment: @sphennings, at the time I posted my answer, the last statement only read, "How can I get enough caffeine to replace my 16oz of coffee a day without being able to purchase it?"  As it was post-apocalypse, I assumed (right or wrong) that he could steal it, scavange it, borrow it, or anything else.  It also didn't specify a temperature or specify that growing it was the specific goal.  Now that it's changed, I'll update my answer.